# my accepted answer is factually incorrect--no recourse?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

My answer to [Can I move 240' and attack in one round by using two riding horses?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73480/23970) is factually incorrect, but was accepted before I realized that. I cannot delete the accepted answer. Is there any way to remove the post?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Flag as “other” and explain the issue in the custom flag area. Moderators have the ability to delete answers even when they've been accepted, and unless there's a good reason not to, such flags are generally acted on.

Before I got my diamond I ran into this at least once and used a custom flag to request my accepted answer be deleted, and that took care of it.